# Opening any Location On Google Map with input as coordinates using App Inventor

Tags: android, google-maps, app-inventor

I want to create an simple android app using **App Inventor 2**.

Here i want to give coordinates i.e. latitude and longitude as input .
I want to display the inputed coordinates on the Google Map.

How can I achieve this using an App Inventor 2?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please first [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `activity starter` component, see also [Using the Activity Starter](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/other/activitystarter.html)

> **Show a map for a location**
>
> If you know a latitude and a longitude, you can use the VIEW action to
>   show a map of the area:
>
> Action: android.intent.action.VIEW
>  
>   DataUri: geo:37.8,-122.23?z=10

A very good way to learn App Inventor is to read the free Inventor's Manual here in the AI2 free online eBook   http://www.appinventor.org/book2 ... the links are at the bottom of the Web page.  The book 'teaches' users how to program with AI2 blocks.
There is a free programming course here http://www.appinventor.org/content/CourseInABox/Intro  and the aia files for the projects in the book are here:  http://www.appinventor.org/bookFiles
How to do a lot of basic things with App Inventor are described here:  http://www.appinventor.org/content/howDoYou/eventHandling  .

Also do the tutorials http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/tutorials.html to learn the basics of App Inventor, then try something and follow the [Top 5 Tips: How to learn App Inventor](https://puravidaapps.com/learn.php)